# Set Sticky enable automatically once ubercart order is completed

Tags: 7, ubercart

I need to set Sticky enable automatically once the customer completes the ubercart order.

I have tried this by creating custom module but didn't work. Here is my code :

```
function mymodule_purchasePaidListing($order){

  $i=0;
  foreach ($order->products as $key => $value) {
    if ($i>=1){
      break;
    }

    if ($i==0){

    $product_node_id = reset($value->data['attributes']['Product Node ID']); 

      if ($product_node_id){
        $node = node_load($product_node_id);

        $node->sticky=1;

        node_save($node);
      }

    } 
  $i++;
  }

}
```

**Note :** I am getting Node id in Product attribute **Product Node ID** mentioned above.

Any Help?

Comment: Most likely the `$product_node_id` does not exist.

Comment: $product_node_id is exist. Can you please let me know how do I print the $order variable ? also let me know how to check whether above function is working or not.

Comment: Use `kprint_r($order)` or `kpr($order)` if you have drush installed, otherwise use `print '<pre>'; var_dump print '</pre>';`, but I can't tell if your function functions or not. From a quick search that I did I found no results for `hook_purchasePaidListing`...

Comment: Is there any other way to set Sticky enable automatically once the customer completes the ubercart order?

Comment: I tried this var_dump($order); But it returns NULL value. Why?

Comment: OK, where did you find the `mymodule_purchasePaidListing($order)` function, is it a hook or yours? If it is yours how do you define that `$order` value, post you code.

Comment: Its my custom function only. Here is my code :
`function custom_biztobiz_purchasePaidListing($order){
$i=0;
  foreach ($order->products as $key => $value) {
    if ($i>=1){ break;}
     if ($i==0){ $product_node_id = reset($value->data['attributes']['Product Node ID']); 
        if ($product_node_id){  $node = node_load($product_node_id);
        $node->sticky=1;
        node_save($node);  }  } 
  $i++;
  } }`

Comment: This is a code which used in that module js file :

`function purchasePaidListing(){
 var product=getParameter("p");
 var url="http://"+window.location.hostname+"/"+"cart/add/e-p415_a13o"+jQuery('#paid-listing-impression').val()+"_a4o"+product+"-m31-s?destination=cart/checkout";
 window.location=url;
}`